# Showing summation of all elements in list

Tags: python

I need to add all elements in a list and print that out. Is it possible to make this

```
x_irp = []
for i in range(1,5):
    for r in range(1,7):
        for p in range(1,4):
            a = "x_{}_{}_{}".format(i,r,p)
            x_irp.append(a)
print(x_irp)

['x_1_1_1', 'x_1_1_2', 'x_1_1_3', 'x_1_2_1', 'x_1_2_2', 'x_1_2_3', 'x_1_3_1', 'x_1_3_2', 'x_1_3_3', 'x_1_4_1', 'x_1_4_2', 'x_1_4_3', 'x_1_5_1', 'x_1_5_2', 'x_1_5_3', 'x_1_6_1', 'x_1_6_2', 'x_1_6_3', 'x_2_1_1', 'x_2_1_2', 'x_2_1_3', 'x_2_2_1', 'x_2_2_2', 'x_2_2_3', 'x_2_3_1', 'x_2_3_2', 'x_2_3_3', 'x_2_4_1', 'x_2_4_2', 'x_2_4_3', 'x_2_5_1', 'x_2_5_2', 'x_2_5_3', 'x_2_6_1', 'x_2_6_2', 'x_2_6_3', 'x_3_1_1', 'x_3_1_2', 'x_3_1_3', 'x_3_2_1', 'x_3_2_2', 'x_3_2_3', 'x_3_3_1', 'x_3_3_2', 'x_3_3_3', 'x_3_4_1', 'x_3_4_2', 'x_3_4_3', 'x_3_5_1', 'x_3_5_2', 'x_3_5_3', 'x_3_6_1', 'x_3_6_2', 'x_3_6_3', 'x_4_1_1', 'x_4_1_2', 'x_4_1_3', 'x_4_2_1', 'x_4_2_2', 'x_4_2_3', 'x_4_3_1', 'x_4_3_2', 'x_4_3_3', 'x_4_4_1', 'x_4_4_2', 'x_4_4_3', 'x_4_5_1', 'x_4_5_2', 'x_4_5_3', 'x_4_6_1', 'x_4_6_2', 'x_4_6_3']
```

I must print this list in a form as x_1_1_1 + x_1_1_2 + x_1_1_3.... 
It has to continue until the last element of list.

Comment: And what's the *problem* with what you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using

```
print(" + ".join(x_irp))
```